# How to use quote annotator

Tags: stanford-nlp

Running

> ./corenlp.sh  -annotators quote -outputFormat xml -file input.txt

on the modified input file

> "Stanford University" is located in California. It is a great university, founded in 1891.

yields the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <document>
    <sentences/>
  </document>
</root>
```

Maybe I misunderstood the intended use of this annotator, but I expected it to mark the parts of the sentence that is between the ".

When I run the script with the "usual" annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner, they are all working well, but adding quote does not change the output. I use the stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09 release.
How can I use the quote annotator and what is it meant to do?

Comment: An update: JSON output and text for quotes is now enabled in the JSONOutputter and TextOutputter as of commit. XML output remains unimplemented because the current xml structure is based around sentences and quotes can span multiple sentences, which makes it non-trivial to implement nicely. https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/commit/a0b6f64cdc2d680fc2a78f18b418dd704df63b2a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build a StanfordCoreNLP object in Java code and run it with the quote annotator, the final Annotation object will have the quotes.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.semgraph.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class PipelineExample {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        // build pipeline
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, quote");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        String text = "\"Stanford University\" is located in California. It is a great university, founded in 1891.";
        Annotation annotation = new Annotation(text);
        pipeline.annotate(annotation);
        System.out.println(annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.QuotationsAnnotation.class));
    }
}
```

Currently none of the outputters (json, xml, text, etc...) output the quotes.  I'll make a note we should add this to the output for future versions.

Comment: It seems not to be included in `3.7.0` could you make a note again or shall we submit an issue?

Comment: Can someone provide information about how to integrate this pipleline in CoreNLP and how to run it in order to get the desired output?

Comment: For me it's is giving Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "quote" requires annotation "CorefChainAnnotation". The usual requirements for this annotator are: tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner
I am using 3.9.1 version

Comment: You'll need to run coref as well to use the quote annotator by default if you want quote attribution.  If you want to run it without coref (and without attribution) use the property quote.attributeQuotes = false